# Calculating PSNR using STFT of sampled signal

Tags: matlab, stft, baseband

I have a baseband IQ sampled signal from a Pluto SDR with a bandwidth B and also fs = B, how can I calculate its PSNR using the STFT of the signal in Matlab.
Do I need to take into account the RBW of the STFT while calculating the PSNR ?